# memory release problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a view and assigned the view to viewcontroller

```
UIView *newView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
```

in viewDidLoad method I have assigned the view to the viewcontroller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.view=newView;
    //[view release]; In this case also the application crashing
}

-(void)dealloc{
   [newView release];//IN this case also the application crashing.
   [super dealloc];
}
```

The crash log is this.
[image]

how to release the newView? or else the viewcontroller itself will take care of releasing the newView.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't seem complete - where are you allocating newView?  You should almost certainly be releasing newView after assigning it to self.view - review the Cocoa memory management guidelines (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most circumstances you will do the following:

```
- (void) loadView {
    // Don't call super here if you assign the view property
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.view = newView;
    [newView release];
    // the view is now owned and retained by the UIViewController
}
```

Apple recommends you allocate the view, assign and release it in `-loadView` and don't worry about it in `-dealloc`. This is important in cases when your view may be purged under low memory conditions.